# Factoring the factorials

Tags: recreational-mathematics, factorial, prime-factorization, conjectures

Just for the fun of it, I've started factoring $n!$ into its prime divisors, and this is what I got for $2\leq n\leq20$:

$$\begin{align}
2! &= 2^\color{red}{1} &S_e=1\\
3! &= 2^\color{red}{1} \cdot 3^\color{red}{1} &S_e=2\\
4! &= 2^3 \cdot 3^\color{red}{1} &S_e=4\\
5! &= 2^3 \cdot 3^\color{red}{1} \cdot 5^\color{red}{1} &S_e=5\\
6! &= 2^4 \cdot 3^2 \cdot  5^\color{red}{1} &S_e=7\\
7! &= 2^4 \cdot 3^5 \cdot 5^\color{red}{1} \cdot 7^\color{red}{1} &S_e=8\\
8! &= 2^7 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^\color{red}{1} \cdot 7^\color{red}{1} &S_e=11\\
9! &= 2^7 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 5^\color{red}{1} \cdot 7^\color{red}{1} &S_e=13\\
10! &= 2^8 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^\color{red}{1} &S_e=15\\
11! &= 2^8 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^\color{red}{1} \cdot 11^\color{red}{1} &S_e=16\\
12! &= 2^{10} \cdot 3^5 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^\color{red}{1} \cdot 11^\color{red}{1} &S_e=19\\
13! &= 2^{10} \cdot 3^5 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^\color{red}{1} \cdot 11^\color{red}{1} \cdot 13^\color{red}{1} &S_e=20\\
14! &= 2^{11} \cdot 3^6 \cdot 5^3 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11^\color{red}{1} \cdot 13^\color{red}{1} &S_e=22\\
15! &= 2^{11} \cdot 3^6 \cdot 5^3 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11^\color{red}{1} \cdot 13^\color{red}{1} &S_e=24\\
16! &= 2^{15} \cdot 3^6 \cdot 5^3 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11^\color{red}{1} \cdot 13^\color{red}{1} &S_e=28\\
17! &= 2^{15} \cdot 3^6 \cdot 5^3 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11^\color{red}{1} \cdot 13^\color{red}{1} \cdot 17^\color{red}{1} &S_e=29\\
18! &= 2^{16} \cdot 3^8 \cdot 5^3 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11^\color{red}{1} \cdot 13^\color{red}{1} \cdot 17^\color{red}{1} &S_e=32\\
19! &= 2^{16} \cdot 3^8 \cdot 5^3 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11^\color{red}{1} \cdot 13^\color{red}{1} \cdot 17^\color{red}{1} \cdot 19^\color{red}{1} &S_e=33\\
20! &= 2^{18} \cdot 3^8 \cdot 5^4 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11^\color{red}{1} \cdot 13^\color{red}{1} \cdot 17^\color{red}{1} \cdot 19^\color{red}{1} &S_e=36\\
\end{align}$$

where $S_e$ is the sum of the exponents. There are lots of interesting patterns to chase here, but I've focused on the prime factors with exponent $1$ (highlighted). My conjecture is,

> In the sequence above, prime factor $p^1$ will appear $p$ times starting from $p!$.

Or, otherwise stated,

> $\forall k = 2p-1$, $k!$ is the last term of the sequence $\{a_n\}=n!$ to have $p^1$ as one of its prime factors.

[I could not find any reasonable pattern concerning $p^2$.]

This might be some well-known fact, but as someone who hasn't seen prime factorization since elementary school I was wondering how this could be proven (or whether it is even right, although it looks like it is).

Comment: Are you aware that the exponents in the prime factorisation of $n!$ are the sums of the corresponding exponents in $1,\ldots,n$?

Comment: So it _is_ a well known fact. :D Again, I started wondering about factoring factorials during my lunch break, when my mind was concentrating on the sandwich rather than on the numbers. Will delete if necessary

Comment: You're not finding reasonable patterns on $p^2$ because the only $p^2$ that are less than $20$ are 4 and 9.

Comment: This is a nice observation. This is because the next multiple of $p$ after $p$ itself is $2p$. So from $p!$ to $(2p-1)!$ the maximum power of $p$ is 1. I am afraid that you could not find pattern concerning $p^2$ because you have made some mistake in your prime factorization. Check from $14!$.

Comment: Hint: in the product defining $k!$ for $k>2p-1$, both $p$ and $2p$ appear.

Comment: No, don't delete the question. My suggestion is that you take a whack on Google before posting though -- in particular check oeis.org. In this case the sequence turns up if you look at the differences (also a good technique). You might not find anything useful there but it helps you post the question by its proper name, making it more searchable in the future, and if you do find the answer you can always post your question and self-answer, which is appreciated.

Comment: A nice observation indeed. For more see the ["Legendre formula"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_formula) rather useful in number theory.

Answer (score 2):

You're just summing up https://oeis.org/A001222. It might be easier to work with this sequence without taking a cumulative sum. Apparently A001222 is called $\Omega(n)$. You can research from there.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps consider this. Say you multiply $(n-1)!$ by $n$ to get $n!$. Then, if you continue multiplying by $n+1$ and $n+2$, etc, you won't multiply by another multiple of $n$ until you get to $2n$. $2n-n$ is n, so the $n^1$ factor will be show up $n$ times before being duplicated.